# Hardly readable push notification on dark background

Tags: android, google-chrome, push-notification, onesignal

I'm using Onesignal.com to send notifications to Web push users.
The notification is displayed correctly for Firefox users, but it's unreadable for Chrome users (black text on a dark background) and the icon is too small.

Here is a screenshot :
[image: Push notification screenshot]

I'm using :
Chrome 55.0.2883.91
Android 6.0
Huawei P9 Light (VNS L31)

Any idea about this problem?

Comment: same problem here, 6 months later I can't find any solution. The strange thing is that Chrome itslef, when sending its notifications like downloads, shows them correctly. I can reproduce this bug only with onesignal.

Comment: Temporarily, I filled the Image field to have a normal display (with a big image)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome on Android customizes the notification's display (to add its own features), and is a bit buggy when displaying the notification in a dark color theme. An open Chrome bug is here describing the issue:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=685181.

I don't think there's anything you can do about this issue from your side, since Chrome handles displaying the notification.